# Randomly matchable and bipartite class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, random-walk, random-graphs, graph-connectivity

I am curios to know at least one example of the following graphs:

i) an infinite class of bipartite graphs that is randomly matchable;

ii) an infinite class of non-bipartite graphs that is randomly matchable;

ii) an example of a graph that has a 1-factor, but is not randomly matchable.

By condition, if every matching of the graph can be extended to a 1-factor then  the graph is said to be a randomly matchable graph. Thus, in my opinion (which may be wrong), a [Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) is an infinite class of bipartite graphs that is randomly matchable. Any help and guidance is welcome to lead me unravel the above graphs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Rado graph is (1) not an infinite class of graphs, but a single graph, and (2) not bipartite.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I never knew Rado graph is not.

Comment: Its most fundamental property is that any finite graph is an induced subgraph of the Rado graph. In particular, the Rado graph contains $C_3$, which is not bipartite; therefore the entire Rado graph cannot be bipartite either.

Comment: Thank you for disproving Rado graphs. It remains to unravel the class of graphs and it appears to me that there's little or no literatures about them- my search is unsuccessful.

Comment: I think you're confused. The words "infinite class of graphs" are not asking you for anything complicated: just to give infinitely many examples (which can be finite). For example, "all even cycles: $C_4, C_6, C_8, \dots$" is an infinite class of bipartite graphs. But it is not a solution to (i), because $C_6$ and higher are not randomly matchable.

Comment: It seems to be $K_{n,n}$, $K_{2n}$ suffices (i) and (ii)